# Remove prefix from string in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy, substring, prefix

I need to remove prefix from String in Groovy if it begins the string (no action otherwise).

If prefix is `groovy`:

- for `groovyVersion`  I expect `Version`
- for `groovy` I expect empty string
- for `spock` I expect `spock`

Right now I use `.minus()`, but when I do

```
'library-groovy' - 'groovy'
```

then as a result I get `library-` instead of `library-groovy`.

What's the groovy way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I dont know much about Groovy but here is my take on this one:

```
def reg = ~/^groovy/   //Match 'groovy' if it is at the beginning of the String
String str = 'library-groovy' - reg

println(str)
```

Answer (score 10):

This is case sensitive and doesn't use a regular expression:

```
​def prefix = 'Groovy';
def string = 'Groovy1234';
def result = '';

if (string.startsWith(prefix)) {
    result = string.substring(prefix.size())
    print result
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This version is plain and simple, but it meets the requirements and is an incremental change to your original:

```
def trimGroovy = { 
    it.startsWith('groovy') ? it - 'groovy' : it
}

assert "Version" == trimGroovy("groovyVersion")
assert "" == trimGroovy("groovy")
assert "spock" == trimGroovy("spock")
assert "library-groovy" == trimGroovy("library-groovy")
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use a regexp:

```
assert 'Version  spock' == 'groovyVersion groovy spock'.replaceAll( /\bgroovy/, '' )
```

Comment: as the method name says, it will replace 'All' occurences, not only the prefix.

Answer (score -2):

**Solution:**  use `-` opreator and cut the right string.

```
def sentence = "remove_me_i_am_ok"
def string_to_be_remove = "remove_me_"

String result = sentence - string_to_be_remove
print("output: ${result}")​

/* output: i_am_ok */
```

Comment: this would also strip the given sequence if the first ocurence is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr even If the string is at the beginning/middle/end of the sequence it should work, tested it.

Comment: for my understanding a prefix is meant to be on the start of the string - that's what the word tells me.